# Adding texture to certain states when plotting maps with R

Tags: r, maps

I'm getting started with maps in R, and I'm facing a problem which I'm not being able to solve.
Suppose the following script:

```
tmp_dir = tempdir()
url_data = "http://www.sharegeo.ac.uk/download/10672/50/English%20Government%20Office%20Network%20Regions%20(GOR).zip"
zip_file = sprintf("%s/shpfile.zip", tmp_dir)
    download.file(url_data, zip_file)
unzip(zip_file, exdir = tmp_dir)
library(maptools)
gor=readShapeSpatial(sprintf('%s/Regions.shp', tmp_dir))
col=gray(gor$NUMBER/sum(gor$NUMBER))
col[5] = NA
plot(gor, col=col)
```

I would like a way to add a texture to the state with missing data on the "col" vector, instead of just leaving it white.
So in this case for example, I'm looking for something like that:

[image]

How can I add textures to specific parts of my plot, specially when working with maps?
I've read about functions like add.texture, but I couldn't use them in such a flexible way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plot.SpatialPolygons()` is capable of using line texture. If the argument `density` isn't `NA`, `plot.SpatialPolygons()` uses line texture.

```
:  # (skip)
library(maptools)
col=gray(gor$NUMBER/sum(gor$NUMBER))
col[5] = NA

plot(gor, col=col)          # It's easy to use the argument `add=T`
plot(gor[5,], add=T, density=10, angle=90, col="blue")      # Left map

## Of cource, you can draw the map at once without `add=T`
col2  <- col
col2[4:5] <- c("red", "blue")

plot(gor, col=col2, density=c(rep(NA,3), 30, 10, rep(NA,4)), 
     angle=c(rep(NA,3), 0, 90, rep(NA,4)))                  # Right map
```

[image]